# ML.net Load From Enumerable Trouble

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I have been struggling to create the proper data structure for ML.net and get it to load into my application. Essentially, I have an application where the training data will be dynamic and the type and/or size will not be known prior to runtime. In addition, I have to convert the training data from a non-standard primitive types (ie. App_Bool, or App_Number... rather than simply using bool or double, etc.) So, this has been proving to be a problem as I try to convert my training data into a generic data type which can then be loaded from memory using the *[LoadFromEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net)* function.
I have four basic data type classes:

```
public class MLIntData
{
    public MLIntData(string label, List<object> l)
    {
        Label = label;
        foreach (App_Integer element in l)
            Features.Add((int)element.Value);
    }

    public List<int> Features { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public string Label { get; set; } = "";
}

public class MLNumberData 
{
    public MLNumberData(string label, List<object> l)
    {
        Label = label;
        foreach (App_Number element in l)
            Features.Add((double)element.Value);
    }

    public List<double> Features { get; set; } = new List<double>();
    public string Label { get; set; } = "";
}

public class MLBoolData 
{
    public MLBoolData(string label, List<object> l)
    {
        Label = label;
        foreach (App_Boolean element in l)
            Features.Add((bool)element.Value);
    }

    public List<bool> Features { get; set; } = new List<bool>();

    public string Label { get; set; } = "";
}

public class MLTextData
{
    public MLTextData(string label, List<object> l)
    {
        Label = label;
        foreach (App_String element in l)
            Features.Add(element.Value.ToString());
    }

    public List<string> Features { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string Label { get; set; } = "";
}
```

So, each base class will contain a label for the data and then a list of features which will either be of type *bool*, *double*, *int*, or *string*.

Now, in my ML.net code I'm trying to load in the training data and then create an *[IDataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataview?view=ml-dotnet)* object of the data. First I loop through the input data (which is originally of the generic type *object*) then create the new classes of data.

```
List<object> data = new List<object>();

for(int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
{
    MLCodifiedData codifiedData = input[i].Value as MLCodifiedData;
    Type dataType = codifiedData.Features[0].GetType();

    if (dataType == typeof(App_Boolean))
    {
        data.Add(new MLBoolData(codifiedData.Label, codifiedData.Features));                       
    }
    else if (dataType == typeof(App_Number))
    {
        data.Add(new MLNumberData(codifiedData.Label, codifiedData.Features));
    }
    else if (dataType == typeof(App_Integer))
    {
        data.Add(new MLIntData(codifiedData.Label, codifiedData.Features));
    }
    if (dataType == typeof(App_String))
    {
        data.Add(new MLTextData(codifiedData.Label, codifiedData.Features));
    }
}

IDataView TrainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<object>(data);
```

I have tried creating a *[schema definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.schemadefinition?view=ml-dotnet)* (which can be passed in as the second parameter in the *LoadFromEnumerable* method, but I can't seem to get that to work. I've also tried creating a schema using the *[schema builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataview?view=ml-dotnet)* to create a schema, but that doesn't seem to work either. Right now, I'm using one of the [datasets that is included in one of the sample files](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/Regression_TaxiFarePrediction/TaxiFarePrediction/Data/taxi-fare-full.csv). And to preempt questions, yes, I know I could simply load the data as file and read it in that way... However, in my app I need to first read in the CSV into memory, then create the data structure so I can't really use many of the examples which are geared toward reading in a CSV file using the *LoadFromTextFile* method. Can anyone provide support as to how I could setup a dynamic in-memory collection and get it converted into a IDataView object?